# Firefox doesn't render background-color correctly due to transparency set on a background element

Tags: css, firefox, transform, gecko

It seems Firefox has some problems in rendering the `background-color` of a figure in the foreground when some figures in the background have `transparency` set;

checkout this [pen](http://codepen.io/maio/pen/VYmzdZ),
 Chrome renders as expected but Firefox doesn't pick-up the  background-color of the figure in the foreground (it seems like it's summing the transparency value).

To better understand the issue try changing the opacity property of the figures in the example.

Any suggestions are welcome.

---

**EDIT 1**
the issue seems to be that in Firefox the opacity of the background element property is stacked on top of the foreground element

Comment: The pen link is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `background:rgba(x,x,x,0.66);` solved the issue in firefox